# Compile Error: Invalid field UserPermissionsKnowledgeUser for SObject User

Tags: apex, trigger, user

This is such a daft question, I have created a trigger in my own salesforce dev environment and it works fine. I try and copy this trigger from my org into our company sandbox and I am getting the following error

> “Error: Compile Error: Invalid field UserPermissionsKnowledgeUser for
>   SObject User at line 3 column 1”

My trigger is ;

```
trigger ContentUser on User (before insert) {
    For (User userinloop : trigger.new) {
        userinloop.UserPermissionsKnowledgeUser = true;
    }   
}
```

UserPermissionsKnowledgeUser  = Salesforce CRM Content User field

My dev org salesforce 14
Sandbox salesforce 14

what the hell is happening ?

Regards
D

Comment: Are your sandbox and production dbs identical in terms of objects, fields, etc?  The field "UserPermissionsKnowledgeUser" isn't visible in my Salesforce production db.

Comment: field label  : Salesforce CRM Content User = UserPermissionsKnowledgeUser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you don't have knowledge on that org or a knowledge license assigned.

Comment: The salesforce field is "Salesforce CRM Content User"  which i belive is api name of UserPermissionsKnowledgeUser

Comment: @user11500: No, that field refers to Knowlege. https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_user.htm

Comment: OOh PepeFloyd you cheeky minx, i think your right, i think i need the field api name of UserPermissionsSFContentUser :P

Comment: Currently this field only gets populated if the user is created, how can i make it fire if the user record is also being edited and saved ?

Comment: @user11500: Instead of (before insert), do (before insert, before update)

Comment: I guess it is as simple as "trigger ContentUser on User (before insert,before update)..................

Comment: HI PepeFloyd 
Already done :) Thanks for your help much appreciated